# What's missing to fold vimscript consecutive comments with "syntax" foldmethod inside function, if, while, etc?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding

This syntax region fold consecutive comments:

```
syn region vimFoldComment
            \ start="^\z(\s*\"\)"
            \ end="\(\z1\)\@!"
            \ transparent fold
            \ contains=ALLBUT, vimFoldComment
```

This, for example:

```
" a
" b 
" c
```

Folds to

```
+-- 3 lines: a-----
```

but doesn't work inside functions, if, etc.
How will I achieve this?

Comment: I don't have that region defined in `syntax/vim.vim`, but if I did I would suspect it needs to be `containedin=ALLBUT,.*String` (and possibly others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by @D.BenKnoble in comments, the problem seems to be that you're using `contains=` instead of `containedin=`.

If you use `containedin=` instead (more specifically, `containedin=ALLBUT,vimFoldComment`), to indicate that your `vimFoldComment` rule can be contained in about any other rule, it starts to work:

```
syn region vimFoldComment
            \ start="^\z(\s*\"\)"
            \ end="\(\z1\)\@!"
            \ transparent fold
            \ containedin=ALLBUT,vimFoldComment
```

But see the NOTE below, on how adding new syntax rules for folding can be an issue.

---

(Original answer:) The syntax definition for Vimscript includes specific rules for the function body and restricts which syntax groups are allowed there through a [`vimFuncBodyList` cluster](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/vim.vim#L239).

So if you want to use a syntax rule (such as your `vimFoldComment`) to define folding, you might need to add that rule to the list of rules that can be contained in specific regions, in this case, the `vimFuncBodyList` cluster, which defines what's allowed inside a function block. You can do that with:

```
syntax cluster vimFuncBodyList add=vimFoldComment
```

---

**NOTE:** Generally, adding new syntax rules to existing syntax can be pretty tricky, as you may end up running into other situations where the list of contained rules is restricted, you might not always have clusters that are easy to modify. You might also end up making the original rules stop matching where they're supposed to.

You might want to look into using a different mechanism to define folds, such as defining a function for [`'foldexpr'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27foldexpr%27).

Answer (score 0):

For more folding than the standard currently (vim 8.1) provides, see [(Fandom) Syntax folding of Vim scripts](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Syntax_folding_of_Vim_scripts)

It has an explanation and a script to add folding for:

- for/endfor
- while/endwhile
- if/elseif/else/endif
- try/catch/finally/endtry
- comments

I recently added this fragment, to provide the comment folding.

```
" Fold multiple comment lines, except those in a continuation line.
syn region vimFoldComment
        \ start=+\v^\z(\s*")(\\ )@!+
        "\ \z(...) marks ... for later reference (with \z1)
        "\ (\\ )@! excludes continuation comments
        \ skip=+^\z1+
        \ end=+^\v(\z1)@!+
        \ fold
        \ contains=@vimCommentGroup
        \ containedin=ALLBUT,@vimNoFold
syn cluster vimNoFold add=vimFoldComment
hi def link vimFoldComment vimComment
```

You will have to create a personal addition to the standard vim syntax file.
As @filbranden already mentioned, this can create problems.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Note that the current version is 8.2+

Comment: That is true; but that is not the version that I tested this on (yet).